# Android Time Picker with milliseconds

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-timepicker

I need to allow my users to enter times using MM:SS.mmm format.  I've had no luck finding documentation for any standard way of doing this on android and can't find a library for it either.  Can someone provide a suggestion for this?  I can write my own but I'd rather not waste time if it's been done already.